# BCP from One Table to Another table in different servers in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two different servers. I need to transfer the data from One **Server table** to another **server table** (both are on same structure) using either `BCP` or using `BULK INSERT`. I need to do this on the run time. Can anybody please help me on this? I have a `linked share` connection established between the servers. Looking for an option to **copy data** faster.

Comment: Have you tried an `INSERT INTO LinkedServer.dbo.Table1 SELECT FROM dbo.Table1`?

Comment: @anustart I have tried inserting through Linked Server. But the memory consumption is high in such case. Just wanted to avoid any performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCP will almost certainly the fastest, however it is not transactional and the error trapping is rather poor.  It's pretty easy to use though, let's say you have `server1` and `server2` each having a `the_database` and `the_table` with the same structure.

- From `server1` go to your command line, `start->run->cmd` *not* Microsoft SQL Management Studio.
- Type: `bcp the_database.dbo.the_table out c:\the_data.txt -T -E`
- Just hit Enter on all the prompts
- Wait for it, and copy `the_data.txt` to `c:\` on `server2`
- On `server2` `TRUNCATE` the_table (unless you want to append, but watch for constraint problems)
- On `server2`, once again go to command line
- Type: `bcp the_database.dbo.the_table in c:\the_data.txt -T -E`
- Magic! Your data has been imported

That will be your fastest solution.  You can also use the `IMPORT` or `EXPORT` wizards inside of Microsoft SQL Management Server which is more of a GUI way to do the same thing, but the `cmd` way will be the fastest way to just copy massive amounts of data (millions of rows).  If you simply type `bcp` from command line you'll see lots of options.

Nothing wrong with doing `bulk insert` across servers for but raw caveman power 'copy data fast' this is the fastest way to do it, imho.

Comment: So are you suggesting to import to a file and then export the data from the file?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  If performance is your top concern, BCP is the way to go.

Comment: @Krish if you have found my answer helpful, please accept and upvote it :)

Comment: Though it was not the same answer I was looking at, I have upvoted and accepted the answer. Thank you very much.